# How do I use the `COPY` command with JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, copy

So I've been working with postgre databases and I noticed that it throws an error sometimes when I try to read a csv file and copy to a table remotely. It works perfectly when I use a buffered reader but i'm trying to see if there's a way i can get i to work using the databases COPY FROM method. It works perfectly on the computer where the database is located but my other computer gets an error.

Error occurs in this line:

```
st.execute("COPY inputdata FROM 'C:\\Users\\JAMES\\Downloads\\V24_Mike_110217_RemovedReturnTrips\\RyderCombiner\\AllNonMatchingWithColNames.csv' CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',';");
```

Here's where I connect to database:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.15:5432/postgres", "postgres", "pass");
```

I read online that maybe STDIN can possibly help me but I haven't been able to get it to work and most examples online are using pqsl. Is there a way I can get tthis to work or do I need to go back to buffered readers?

**UPDATE**:

So I've tried using the CopyManager API but it has an error when trying to make a connection using DBUtil as it is not recognized even though I downloaded the jar file from this website: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/download_dbutils.cgi

Code:

```
    Connection connection = DBUtil.getConnection("POSTGRES");
    String sql = "COPY inputdata FROM 'C:\\Users\\JAMES\\Downloads\\V24_Mike_110217_RemovedReturnTrips\\RyderCombiner\\AllNonMatchingWithColNames.csv' CSV HEADER DELIMITER ','";
    CopyManager copyManager = new CopyManager((BaseConnection)connection); 
    copyManager.copyIn(sql);
```

I get the error in the first line with DBUtil...is importing the jar file the only way to make jdbc recognize this variable?

**UPDATE2**:

Thanks again guys I ended up getting the copyin to work by following the given link and a few adjustments.

```
public static void readInputData(String inputDataFile, Statement st) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException {
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.15:5432/postgres", "postgres", "pass");
    String sql = "COPY INPUTDATA FROM stdin CSV HEADER DELIMITER ','";
    BaseConnection pgcon = (BaseConnection)connection;
    CopyManager mgr = new CopyManager(pgcon);
    try {
        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(inputDataFile)));
        long rowsaffected  = mgr.copyIn(sql, in);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getClass().getName() + ": " + ex.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `copy` refers to a file **on the server**. If you want to use the copy functionality through JDBC you need to use the CopyManager API of the JDBC driver: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46991315/330315

Comment: mmhmm...I've been trying to get the CopyManager API to work but it has a problem with recognizing DBUtil even though I downloaded and added the jar file to my library.

Comment: You should use the answer in a @a_horse_with_no_name's link as a template, you're not using copymanager right. You're call to `copyIn` lacks a `BufferedReader` object

Comment: Following that template I was able to get it working perfectly. Now I'm having an issue writing that  same csv file to a txt file on the client computer, it seems neither copyin or copyout are giving me what I want.

Comment: Figured it out, instead of a buffered reader you have to use filewrite instead with CopyOut and then yuo can copy onto a local file thats not on the server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It works perfectly when I use a buffered reader but i'm trying to see if there's a way i can get i to work using the databases COPY FROM method. It works perfectly on the computer where the database is located but my other computer gets an error.

No you have to use a [`BufferedReader`, or `InputStream`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html)

1. `COPY` opens a file handle **on the server**. It just needs a path, because it can open and manage its own file handle, and that's more efficient.
2. For client-side `COPY`, you have to use [libpq `PQputCopyData`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-copy.html#LIBPQ-COPY-SEND). Internally, client-side `COPY` is `COPY FROM STDIN`. The client has to send the data. This is what psql's `\COPY` does internally. In Java, the [function that calls `PQputCopyData` is `copyIn` which requires a `BufferedReader`, or `InputStream`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html).